# How to define a protocol that acts as a host for another protocol with associated types

Tags: swift

Is it possible to define a protocol that has a member that is also a protocol but has an associated type:

```
protocol Thing {
    associatedtype T
    func action(value: T)
}

protocol ThingHost {
    var thing: Thing! {get set}
}
```

This generates a compiler error, which makes sense:

> Protocol 'Thing' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

But I'm curious if there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use another associated type, in `ThingHost`.

```
associatedtype Thing: ModuleName.Thing
```